# Shadows black even when a light is on top of it

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm building a game engine in ThreeJS, and I'm having an issue with lighting.

Basically I'm building a grid-based RPG, each cell(dimension is 10 x 10) contains a floor and optionally a ceiling. I want the ceiling to cast a soft shadow on the floors(to simulate open environments as well as dungeons). I have 3 lights to achieve this.

This is a basic diagram, showing the 3 lights, the floor are built with 4 meshes, the ceiling are 2 meshes, using LambertMaterial

[image]

I'm a beginner in the topic of lights/shadows in ThreeJS...basically I notice the shadow projected is entirely black, even when the lower PointLight is there.(On the 2 meshes on the "ceiling", only the mesh nearest to the camera is casting shadows, for the purpose of this example). How can I achieve a more "enlightened" shadow?

Also, I'm noticing several artifacts being generated in the meshes...can this be produced by the used of several meshes instead of only two, one for the ceiling and other for the floor? I'm doing this with one mesh per floor cell because I want to have more than one texture on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've ditched three.js, ported the code to http://www.babylonjs.com/ and follow the MUCH better documentation and tutorials I've found there. Everything worked as a charm.